# No definition found for user control member in compile time

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've run into the following problem:

I've got a user control, on which I'v got a chart component developed by me. I'm trying to use the user control in the main application, and reach the chart component member from the main app's code something like this:

```
((VibraLysisUserControls.UC_SensorMonitor)(docContent.Content)).TimeDomainGraph
```

where TimeDomainGraph is the copmonent which resides in separate the dll in the project.
The interesting point comes here: When I put the above line into the code behind I've got the following error message in compile time:

> 'VibraLysisUserControls.UC_SensorMonitor' does not contain a
>   definition for 'TimeDomainGraph' and no extension method
>   'TimeDomainGraph' accepting a first argument of type
>   'VibraLysisUserControls.UC_SensorMonitor' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I comment out that line and go to debug the application, I can reach that member in the QuickWatch window when I stop the app at the point where I would like to use this. In fact, I just copied the code from the QuickWatch window, where it works perfectly.

Anybody has some idea, what the hell is going on here? Why I can't reach a property in the code, which works just perfectly in the QuickWath window during debugging?

**Update:**

The problem is solved. I found out with some help. It was a visibility problem in XAML. Thanks for your help.

Br,
Csaba

Comment: It can be a matter of class hierarchy (TimeDomainGraph, for example, is defined in some class that inherits from uc_sensormonitor). Your code is not enough to tell, though

Comment: Kindly check the access specifier for the Method "TimeDomainGraph" . Also check the definition once.